# How can I live and work in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, tips-and-tricks, residency, working-visas

I'm a Mexican computer science engineer, and an entry-level pen tester. I would like to emigrate to the United Kingdom. Initially, I would like to enter on a work visa but, ideally, I would like to live there five years so that I would be eligible for permanent residency.

As a tourist, I can stay 6 months in the UK without a visa. If I go home, and return to the UK, are those 6 months counted toward the 5 years needed for a residence permit? Can I work as a freelance. Should I go to the UK and apply for jobs?

I want to do this because I want to be close of my girlfriend, who is English and lives in Gloucester. I know she could help me a lot , but we are young; she's 18 , and I'm 21 . I want to wait until she turns 21 to marry her.  How can I accomplish all of this?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is incredibly confusing and asks several things at once. So let me make some statements that will probably clear up things for you.

If you come to the UK as a tourist **you are not allowed to work.** It is illegal. Also nobody will give you a job, at least not as any kind of engineer. You need to apply for a work permit. It doesn't matter if you are working freelance it is still illegal. If you are caught doing this you will probably be banned from the UK.

Time spent as a tourist does not count towards the five years for residency. You need to be resident, I.e. live in the UK, and living in the UK without a visa is illegal.

If you have specific questions about moving to the UK to work you should ask on our [Expatriates site](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com).